# Bubble sort doubts

Tags: c, sorting

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main( )
{
     int a[100]; 
     int i, j, temp, n ;
     printf("how many numbers you want to sort : \n");
     scanf("%d",&n);
     printf("Enter %d number values you want to sort\n", n);
     for(j=0; j<n; j++)
     scanf("%d",&a[j]);

     for(j=1;j<n;j++)
```

how do we know that the above mentioned for loop must be repeated n times,how should one develop logic for that ,I know that the inner for loop will only help to sort the elements in the list once,then why should we repeat inner loop n times

```
     {
          for(i=0; i<n; i++)
          {
               if(a[i]>a[i+1])
               {
                     temp=a[i];
                     a[i]=a[i+1];
                     a[i+1]=temp;
               } 
          }
     }

     printf ( "\n\nArray after sorting:\n") ;

     for ( i = 0 ; i <n ; i++ )
     printf ( "%d\t", a[i] ) ;
     getch();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

in the internal loop you will find maximum. you can't be sure other numbers are sorted.

other version (faster):

```
do
for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) do:
  if A[i] > A[i+1] then
    swap(A[i], A[i+1])
  end if
end for
n = n-1
```

while n > 1

(not checking maximum of previous loops)

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand that code, extract the code that outputs the current values of the array to a separate function. Then, every time you swap two elements, output a message saying which elements you swapped and what the resulting array now looks like.

You will not only see how it sorts, but you will also find a bug in the code. I'd try to help you further, but I don't want to spoil you the learning experience.